# Netbeans 8.2: JBOSS: How to configure program properties

Tags: netbeans, jboss, server, arguments, netbeans-8

I have JBOSS EAP 6.4 added inside netbeans 8.2. When I navigate to menu:
services -> server -> right click on JBOSS server -> properties -> platform

I see option only to configure VM properties. I also need to configure path to properties file using flag "-P". But I do not see any option to do so.

In eclipse we can configure program properties and VM properties separately for application server. Any idea on how to do it in Netbeans 8.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not found option to configure program arguments, for JBOSS EAP, in Netbeans 8.2 yet. But as a workaround:

- I copied my existing standalone.bat to new file "standalone_orig.bat"
- Then I modified standalone.bat file to call "standalone_orig.bat" and pass program arguments to it.
- Contents of standalone.bat would look like"

  call "standalone_orig.bat" -P <_path_to_properties_file_>

It works! Hope it helps you. Let me know if you find any option to do it from netbeans 8.2 instead.

Comment: Nice workaround, I tried different approaches with WildFly 10 and nothing else worked. Its definitely a problem with Netbeans 8.* and not the WildFly/Jboss Server.